# JMockit | trying to define different return values based on parameters but getting unexpected results

Tags: java, jmockit

I've got a class like the following:

```
class A
{
   public method doSomething()
   {
      //....

      DAO dataAccessor = new DAO();
      List<Object> result1 = dataAccessor.getData(dataAccessor.getSql1());
      List<Object> result2 = dataAccessor.getData(dataAccessor.getSql2());

      //.. do some stuff with the results

}
```

Now, I use jMockit for testing the above function, by mocking the `DAO` class.

This is how my test class looks like:

```
class A_Test
{
    private A myAClass;

    @Mocked DAO mockedDAO;

    List<Object> resultToSql1, resultToSql2;

    // ... Some initializations...

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething()
    {
        new NonStrictExpectations()
        {
                mockedDAO.getSql1(); result = "SQL1";
                mockedDAO.getData(withEqual("SQL1")); result = resultToSql1;

                mockedDAO.getSql2(); result = "SQL2";
                mockedDAO.getData(withEqual("SQL2")); result = resultToSql2;
        };

        myAClass.doSomething(); 
    }
}
```

Now, it seems that the second expectation regarding `getData()` masks the first one, i.e. the mock object behaves as if I never declared the first lines in the expectation (the ones that handle `sql1`):

The first call to `getData()` returns empty collection, instead of the values with which I initialized `resultToSql1`. The second call returns `resultToSql2`, as expected.

If I comment the following line:

```
mockedDAO.getData(withEqual("SQL2")); result = resultToSql2;
```

the first call is returning what I defined - `resultToSql1`, and the second returns empty collection.
This makes sense.

So, what am I doing wrong? ?How can I define two different return values from `getData()` based on the parameters of the call?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, After digging more deeply inside the manual, I found that:

> ...But what if a test needs to decide the result of a recorded invocation based on the arguments it will receive at replay time? We can do it through a `mockit.Delegate` instance ...

So, in order to solve the above problem, the expectations block should look like this:

```
    new NonStrictExpectations()
    {
            mockedDAO.getSql1(); result = "SQL1";
            mockedDAO.getSql2(); result = "SQL2";

            mockedDAO.getData(anyString);
            result = new mockit.Delegate()
            {
                List<Object> getData(String sql)
                {
                    if (sql.equals("SQL1"))
                        return resultToSql1;
                    if (sql.equals("SQL2"))
                        return resultToSql2;
                    return null;
                }
            }
    };
```

Comment: This solution works, but the original version should too. What happens is that JMockit (erronously) considers the two recorded `mockedDAO.getData(withEqual(...))` expectations to be *equivalent*, because the only difference is in the value passed to the `withEqual(x)` matcher. To avoid the problem, simply remove the argument matchers and pass `"SQL1"` and `"SQL2"` directly. (`withEqual(x)` should almost never be used). In any case, I will try to fix the issue in JMockit.

Comment: Rogerio, thanks. I tried with and without the withEqual(x) matcher, and got the same results.

Comment: It worked for me, when not using the withEqual matchers. And now I fixed the problem, so it works even with the matchers. If it still fails for you, then the problem is something else.